# SQL grouping records from a log table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which records each event in a system such as 'Queued', 'Started', 'Finished', 'Failed' etc... There are a lot more steps in the table but these are all I am interested in.

I select from this only the events I want

```
SELECT [Id]
,[EventTime]
,[Message]
FROM [Log] 
WHERE [Message] LIKE '%Queued%'
OR [Message] LIKE '%Started%'
OR [Message] LIKE '%Finished%'
OR [Message] LIKE '%Failed%'
```

Which gives me something similar to

```
Id      EventTime  Message
5764    2013-12-20 17:52:25.037 Queued
5764    2013-12-20 17:53:09.767 Started
5765    2013-12-20 17:55:50.403 Queued
5764    2013-12-20 17:57:07.503 Finished
5765    2013-12-20 17:57:39.010 Started
5765    2013-12-20 17:58:05.553 Failed
```

What I would like to end up from this query is a recordset in the following format

Id, QueuedTime, StartTime, FinishedTime, Duration, Status

Now the Status Column should be 'Queued if there is a QueuedTime only, 'InProgress' if there is a Start but no Finish Time', 'Success' if There is a Start and Finish Time and 'Failed' if there is a failed time.

I know i will need some sort of case statement for the Status column but I am not sure how to get it in the format with everything for one Id on the same row.

Can anyone provide some assistance on how to achieve this?

Comment: Tried `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END` using sub-queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with multiple LEFT OUTER JOINs, but be aware that the performance can be bad if your're having a lot of data. Queurying the *message* column with LIKE is not a really good idea as well from a performance viewpoint.

Did you think of using some kind of ETL tool to prepare the data before loading it to the DB (assuming that it comes from an external source)?

Anyway, here's what you can do:

```
select
    q.id,
    q.eventtime as QueuedTime,
    s.eventtime as StartTime,
    f.eventtime as FinishTime,
    f.eventtime-s.eventtime as Duration,
    case
        when fail.id is not null then 'Failed'
        when (q.eventtime is not null and s.eventtime is null and f.eventtime is null) then 'Queued'
        when (q.eventtime is not null and s.eventtime is not null and f.eventtime is null) then 'InProgress'
        when (q.eventtime is not null and s.eventtime is not null and f.eventtime is not null) then 'Success'
    end as Status
from
    (
        select
            distinct id,
            eventtime
        from
            log
        where
            message like '%Queued%'
    ) q
left outer join
    (
        select
            distinct id,
            eventtime
        from
            log
        where
            message like '%Started%'
    ) s
on
    q.id = s.id
left outer join
    (
        select
            distinct id,
            eventtime
        from
            log
        where
            message like '%Finished%'
    ) f
on
    q.id = f.id
left outer join
    (
        select
            distinct id,
            eventtime
        from
            log
        where
            message like '%Failed%'
    ) fail
on
    q.id = fail.id
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a missing variable for grouping all those logs in to one session.

in your query they may be several logs with status "Started" so you need to have a "requestId" or something similar that will contain 1 log from each type.

Comment: The Id column should take car of this. It is more of a jobid than a row identifier

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT ID,MIN(EventTime),MAX(EventTime),TIMEDIFF(MAX(EventTime),MIN(EventTime)) * 24*60*60 AS DURATION,Message
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this: (Sorry I just know Oracle SQL and the time format might be wrong, but that's my basic idea :))

```
SELECT (
        SELECT min (to_timestamp(EventTime|| ' ' || substr(Message,0,12),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'))
             - max (to_timestamp(EventTime|| ' ' || substr(Message,0,12),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'))
          FORM log q
         WHERE q.id = b.id
           AND Message like '%Queued%'
       ) AS QueuedTime
  FROM log b
```